# Destroy Banner/Interstitial ads of AdMob?

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, unityscript

I have a banner which only needs to be shown in main menu. And I want to show interstitials whenever player finish the game and about to return back to mainmenu. There is no problem for requesting and showing ads. However, google says me that

```
When you are finished with a BannerView or InterstitialAd, make sure to call the Destroy() method before dropping your reference to it.

bannerView.Destroy();
interstitial.Destroy();

This notifies the plugin that the object should be garbage collected. Failure to call this method will result in memory leaks.
```

I dont know when I should destroy my ads? Eachtime player exit game (For banner)? Eachtime player goes from mainmenu to game (For banner)? Should I destroy interstitials after showing it and request back when I want to show again?

Answer (score 1):

You should call `destroy()` before you lose a reference to the ad variable. So if your ads are on ActivityB and you exit to ActivityA, then you should be calling `ad.destroy()` in the `onDestroy()` method of ActivityB.